# Can anyone explain the logic behind this simple logic? I'm lost

Tags: c++, logic, do-while

I was just trying out the do while loop in C++, while I came up with an idea of having the descriptions, or whatever it's called, within the brackets after the while in a do while loop do multiple things.
So here's my initial logic: I have an already set up `password` variable and an `input` variable. If the two things match, then it would get out of the loop and output "correct password", else wise it would keep going back to the loop, output "wrong password" and so it goes on. Here's my code:

```
// do while
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int input, password=19960819;
    do{
        cout << "Type your password:" ;
        cin >> input;
    }while(input!=password && cout << "wrong password" << endl); 
    cout << "correct password" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting that even though I had the correct answer inputted, I would still have it output "wrong password". I thought that `cout << "wrong password" << endl` part would always return as `true`, which should also be executed no matter how, and that the only factor would be the `input!=password` part. However, the results were actually perfect, which wasn't what I was expecting... Can anyone explain the logic? I was challenging myself to not use `if` or other logic, but simply using the `do while` logic to reach this result, but I don't get the reason why it's working now...

Comment: Read about the "short-circuiting" behaviour of `&&` (and `||`) in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Worth noting that even though short circuiting can lead to bugs if your logic expects both statements to be executed, it is really important for other things like being able to do `if ((foo != nullptr) && (foo->bar()))`

Answer (score 12):

C++ uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for *built-in<sup>1</sup>* boolean operators, meaning that when you do:

```
A && B
```

`B` is evaluated only if `A` is `true`, because if `A` is `false`, the whole expression is `false` (whatever the value of `B`).

So in:

```
input != password && cout << "wrong password" << endl
```

When `input != password` is `false` (when you enter the correct password), the second operand `cout << "wrong password" << endl` is not evaluated, and thus nothing is outputed.

---

Extra details on the evaluation of the conditions:

- The type of `input != password` is `bool`;
- The type of `cout << "..." << endl` is `std::ostream&`;
- A [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) is [convertible to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) either directly (since C++11) or using the conversion to `void*` (C++03).

Since there is no `operator&&(bool, [const] std::ostream&)` and `std::ostream` is convertible to `bool`, the built-in `operator&&(bool, bool)` is used here, so short-circuit evaluation applies<sup>2</sup>.

When `input != password` is `true` (you entered a wrong password), `cout << "..." << endl` is evaluated, and then converted to a `bool` value, which will by `true` most of the time<sup>3</sup>, thus allowing the loop to continue.

When `input != password` is `false`, short-circuit prevents `cout << "..." << endl` from being evaluated, and nothing is sent to the output.

<sub><sup>1</sup> For overloaded operators, short-circuit evaluation no longer applies. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> You could add a user-defined overload for `&&` before `main`, e.g. `bool operator&&(bool b, std::ostream &s) { return b && (bool)s; }`, to see that short-circuit only applies for built-in operator.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> There is no guarantee that this returns `true`, since the stream could be in a failure state, but this is *unlikely* with `std::cout`.</sub>

Comment: I would note that short-circuiting only applies to built-in types, not when the operator is overloaded.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: actually it only no longer applies if `&&` is *overloaded*.

Comment: @Bathsheba  is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical  incorrect?  *"but overloaded operators behave like regular function calls and always evaluate both operands "*

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe That's what Bathsheba said, short-circuit is only "disabled" if the operator is overloaded, not if you use a custom type.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe You can have a built-in type, e.g. `A`, convertible to `bool`, thus `A() && A()` will perform short-circuit with a non-built-in type.

Comment: ...which is *exactly* what is going on here. As a final remark, `&&` is always a sequencing point.

Comment: You should add that `cout << ...` is evaluated to `true` which allows to continue the loop

Comment: Thanks, @Holt, really appreciate your explanations~ Now I get the reason:)

Answer (score 2):

`cout << "wrong password" << endl` always evaluates to `true` (via a conversion to `bool` operator) and has the side effect of outputting that text.

But that is only evaluated if `input != password`, due to the short-circutting nature of `&&`.

It's rather cute, really. Personally though, I'd write

`} while (input != password && std::cout << "wrong password\n");`

Note that this is reliant on `std::basic_ios::operator bool` which has changed subtly from C++11. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool. In many ways it's better to avoid flashy code like this.

Comment: Thanks, @Bathsheba, now everything makes sense:)

Answer (score 1):

This is because && and || are evaluated in short-circuit. So, for example, A && B would evaluate true if both (and only both) A and B are true, but (and here is the short-circuit) it would be false if A or B is false, so when A is false, there is no need to evaluate B.

In your scenario, when the comparaisson 'input!=password' is false (i.e. input == password), it stops evaluating the expression.

Hope this helps :)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now~